How to change my document's font
I just finished writing my thesis, and I'd like to change the type of my font to the same font type as in this image.
With a font of 12pts and a line spacing of 1.5 cm

I'm using overleaf and the compiler is pdfLaTeX and here's what I put before my \begin{document} :
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[left=4cm, right=2.5cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}  % Charge geometry une seule fois avec toutes les options

\input{settings/Settings}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\pagestyle{plain}

And in my settings.tex file I have this :
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{times}
% Packages
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% Couleur des liens en bleu
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue,
    citecolor=blue
}

% Personnalisation des entêtes et pieds de page
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}  % Numérotation des pages au centre en bas



\lstset{
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily, % Taille de la police et famille de polices
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},         % Couleur des mots-clés
  stringstyle=\color{red},           % Couleur des chaînes
  commentstyle=\color{green},        % Couleur des commentaires
  numbers=left,                      % Numéros de ligne à gauche
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},     % Style des numéros de ligne
  stepnumber=1,                      % Numéroter chaque ligne
  numbersep=10pt,                    % Séparation des numéros de ligne et du code
  showstringspaces=false,            % Ne pas montrer les espaces dans les chaînes
  tabsize=4,                         % Taille des tabulations
  breaklines=true,                   % Retour à la ligne automatique
  breakatwhitespace=true,            % Retour à la ligne uniquement aux espaces
  frame=single,                      % Bordure autour du code
  captionpos=b,                      % Légende en bas
  escapeinside={\%*}{*)},            % Délimiteurs pour l'échappement LaTeX
  morekeywords={*,...}               % Ajout de mots-clés supplémentaires
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{utf8}
\setcode{utf8}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color,pxfonts,fix-cm}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage{wasysym}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{framed}
\graphicspath{{/api/}}


\usepackage{adjustbox}

\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, text width=8em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\tikzstyle{section} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, minimum height=30em, minimum width=10em, text centered]
\tikzstyle{sectionDW} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, minimum height=15em, minimum width=10em, text centered]
\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse, node distance=3cm, minimum height=2em]
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf-umlcd}

\usepackage{mathpazo}
\linespread{1.05}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-uml} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{savetrees}


\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}

\newcommand\summaryname{Abstract}
\newenvironment{Abstract}%
    {\small\begin{center}%
    \bfseries{\summaryname} \end{center}}



\def\ThesisType{M} 


        

            

\definecolor{color_61970}{rgb}{0.121569,0.286275,0.490196}
\definecolor{color_283006}{rgb}{1,1,1}
\definecolor{color_29791}{rgb}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{color_155902}{rgb}{0.498039,0.498039,0.498039}
\definecolor{color_105259}{rgb}{0.298039,0.298039,0.298039}
\definecolor{color_244279}{rgb}{0.847059,0.847059,0.847059}
\definecolor{color_219454}{rgb}{0.74902,0.74902,0.74902}
\definecolor{color_156895}{rgb}{0.501961,0.501961,0.501961}


Welcome to TeX.SE.

Thank you @Mico

Off-topic: Instead of providing five [5] separate xxxxcolor=blue options in the argument of \hypersetup, you could state allcolors=blue.

Do you have access to the pdf file from which you've provided a screenshot? If so, under File - Document Properties, you should be able to retrieve a list of the fonts embedded in the pdf file.

No, I don't have access to that

Incidentally, nothing good whatsoever can come from loading a package twice or more times (cf amsmath, xcolor, and probably a few more). Worse yet is the employment obsolete and deprecated packages (cf. utf8, times, and pxfonts), especially if you're going to clobber the packages with packages loaded later on.

You're loading packages multiple times without any check for consistency.
For instance, you load
times pxfonts mathpazo
The first package is obsolete and chooses Times as the main font; the second one chooses a (deprecated) clone of Palatino; the third one chooses another clone of Palatino.
You have also multiple settings of \pagestyle. It makes no sense to set the page style to empty, then to fancy and finally to plain.
The usefulness of the utf8 package is very dubious; latexsym exists only for back compatibility and is superseded by amssymb; loading color along with xcolor is useless; fix-cm might be useful, but only if you don't load other font packages; the option utf8x to inputenc is deprecated; you ***DON'T*** want savetrees` for the final version of your thesis.
The command \tikzstyle has been deprecated for several years.
Here's a reorganized and cleaned up version of your preamble. Now check whether all the loaded packages are actually useful for your thesis.
In the future, avoid reusing preambles given to you by friends.
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

%%% FIRST LOAD PACKAGES

\usepackage[
  left=4cm,
  right=2.5cm,
  top=3cm,
  bottom=3cm
]{geometry}  % Charge geometry une seule fois avec toutes les options

% language and fonts
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
%\usepackage{arabtex} % do you really need it?
%\usepackage{times} % deprecated, chooses Times
%\usepackage{pxfonts} % deprecated, uses Palatino
%\usepackage{mathpazo} % uses Palatino
\usepackage{fix-cm} % for Computer Modern
\usepackage{pifont}

% graphics and friends
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta}
%\usepackage{tikz-uml} % not on CTAN
\usepackage{pgf-umlcd}

\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{framed} % Really?

% layout
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap} % please, think again about this

% math
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{wasysym}

% tables and listings
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{longtable}


% hyperlinks: must be last
\usepackage{hyperref}

%%% SETTINGS

% Couleur des liens en bleu
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=blue,
  filecolor=blue,
  urlcolor=blue,
  citecolor=blue
}

% Personnalisation des entêtes et pieds de page
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}  % Numérotation des pages au centre en bas

% listings
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily, % Taille de la police et famille de polices
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},         % Couleur des mots-clés
  stringstyle=\color{red},           % Couleur des chaînes
  commentstyle=\color{green},        % Couleur des commentaires
  numbers=left,                      % Numéros de ligne à gauche
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},     % Style des numéros de ligne
  stepnumber=1,                      % Numéroter chaque ligne
  numbersep=10pt,                    % Séparation des numéros de ligne et du code
  showstringspaces=false,            % Ne pas montrer les espaces dans les chaînes
  tabsize=4,                         % Taille des tabulations
  breaklines=true,                   % Retour à la ligne automatique
  breakatwhitespace=true,            % Retour à la ligne uniquement aux espaces
  frame=single,                      % Bordure autour du code
  captionpos=b,                      % Légende en bas
  escapeinside={\%*}{*)},            % Délimiteurs pour l'échappement LaTeX
  morekeywords={*,...}               % Ajout de mots-clés supplémentaires
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\graphicspath{{/api/}}

%% TikZ styles
\tikzset{
  block/.style={
    rectangle,
    draw,
    text width=8em,
    text centered,
    rounded corners,
    minimum height=4em,
  },
  line/.style={draw, -latex'},
  section/.style={
    rectangle,
    draw,
    fill=blue!20,
    minimum height=30em,
    minimum width=10em,
    text centered,
  },
  sectionDW/.style={
    rectangle,
    draw,
    fill=blue!20,
    minimum height=15em,
    minimum width=10em,
    text centered,
  },
  cloud/.style={
    draw,
    ellipse,
    node distance=3cm,
    minimum height=2em,
  },
}

% colors
\definecolor{color_61970}{rgb}{0.121569,0.286275,0.490196}
\definecolor{color_283006}{rgb}{1,1,1}
\definecolor{color_29791}{rgb}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{color_155902}{rgb}{0.498039,0.498039,0.498039}
\definecolor{color_105259}{rgb}{0.298039,0.298039,0.298039}
\definecolor{color_244279}{rgb}{0.847059,0.847059,0.847059}
\definecolor{color_219454}{rgb}{0.74902,0.74902,0.74902}
\definecolor{color_156895}{rgb}{0.501961,0.501961,0.501961}

% final settings
%%%% for Palatino
%\linespread{1.05}

%% personal commands
\newcommand\summaryname{Abstract}
\newenvironment{Abstract}%
    {\small\begin{center}%
    \bfseries{\summaryname} \end{center}}

\newcommand\ThesisType{M} 


\begin{document}

\chapter{Title}

This is in Computer Modern, just like the font in the picture you show.
Sorry for using English, but I don't trust my French.
Note how ugly is the chapter header.

\end{document}


Yes, the chapter header is really ugly: a patchwork of fonts, with a layout that emphasizes what's less important.

+1. One might also recommend replacing linkcolor=blue, filecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue, citecolor=blue with allcolors=blue.
